# Room and debugging not working in WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-room, android-workmanager, android-debug

Custom WorkerManager

```
class CustomWorker(
val
context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
override fun doWork(): Result {

    val appDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(context).appDao()

    appDao.deleteAllRecords().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(object : CompletableObserver {
            override fun onComplete() {
                Log.d("WorkManager", "onComplete")
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                Log.d("WorkManager", "onSubscribe")
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                Log.d("WorkManager", "onError")
            }

        })
  Log.d("WorkManager", "WorkManager")
           Looper.prepare()
           context.toast("Hellow")
           Looper.loop().
    return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Calling the WorkManager

```
fun createWorkerForClearingDb() {
    val oneTimeWorkRequest =
        OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CustomWorker::class.java)
            .setInitialDelay(2L, TimeUnit.HOURS).build()
    WorkManager.getInstance().beginUniqueWork(
        AppConstants.Work.DELETE_TASK,
        ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
        oneTimeWorkRequest
    ).enqueue()
}
```

Dependencies

```
//room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
//rx-java
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxandroid_version"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$rxkotlin_version"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxjava_version"   
ext.rxjava_version = "2.2.12"
ext.rxkotlin_version = "2.4.0"
ext.rxandroid_version = "2.1.1"
ext.rxjava_adapter_version = "2.4.0"
ext.room_version = '2.2.0-rc01'
```

However, I'm able to get the log and toast working.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after adding `open` to the class.

```
open class CustomWorker(
val
context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParams)
```

Sound's a bit strange but now everything is working fine.